# When I put swiftui and rectangle and text side by side, I have difficulties in designing it

Tags: swiftui, view

```
    VStack(alignment: .leading){
        VStack{
            HStack{
                Rectangle().background(Color.blue).frame(width: 6)
                VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 2) {
                   Text("test")
                       .foregroundColor(.green)
                       .padding(.leading, 2)
                   
                   Text("long or short text")
                }.padding(.vertical,4)
            } 
            .frame(width: 255, alignment: .leading)

            .background(Color.black.opacity(0.12))
            .cornerRadius(12)
            .padding(.trailing, 10)
            .padding(.leading, 14)
            .padding(.top, 6)
        }
        
    }
```

I want the height of the text values in the rectangle and vstack to be the same, that is, a thin line justified to the left, but I am trying to push in the rectangle in push out view. I don't know any other way to make it work.

Actually

```
Rectangle().background(Color.blue).frame(width: 6) 
Rectangle().background(Color.blue).frame(width: 6,height: (VStack , texts height))
```

I don't know how long the text will be
or is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the bar on the left to an overlay. Something like this (you may want to tweak the padding):

```swift
var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .leading,spacing: 2) {
        Text("test")
            .foregroundColor(.green)
            .padding(.leading, 2)

        Text("long or short text")
    }
    .padding(.vertical, 4)
    .padding(.leading, 20) // Reserve space for the overlay
    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
        Color.blue.frame(width: 6)
    }
    .frame(width: 255, alignment: .leading)
    .background(Color.black.opacity(0.12))
    .cornerRadius(12)
}
```

[image: TextWithBlueBar]